# Raspberry Pi Linux настройка выхода в интернет через usb модем, используя net core

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, usb

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - имеется Raspberry Pi с usb модемами, через curl выбирая usb интерфейс, получается отправить HTTP запрос и получить страничку. На c#  net core сделал утилиту, которая получает доступ к сетевым интерфейсам и отправляет на внешний ip моего сервера сообщение посредством udp/tcp протокола. Через ethernet интерфейс сообщения доходят до сервера, через usb интерфейсы вообще никак сообщения не доходят. Возможно ли средствами net core настроить на малинке отправку сообщений через usb модемы?

Comment: курл очень умная вещь в этом плане. повторить на сишарпе будет стоить много. могу подсказать как разрулить это на сетевом стеке линукс, но курл тут бьёт напрямую.

Comment: Было бы неплохо

Comment: Юзал nc для отправки сообщений по udp на внешний айпишник другого сервака. Сообщения доходят, но он использует ethernet. Попытки выставить usb интерфейс на nc через опцию - s ни к чему не привели.

Comment: в курле есть хаки для обхода маршрутизации ядра. По мне лучше настроить ip route rule. Сколько модемов там у Вас?

Comment: 3 модема на данный момент, возможно ещё парочку добавлю потом